# Can't send the checkbox value to php

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I'm new to PHP and also OOP, so when I send to the database I want to post it MorseCoded. The problem is when I tick the checkbox,the checkbox value is '0' and it should be one.
index.php
This is the checkbox

```
        <input type="checkbox" id="NSSIOWYDBEI" value="1"  name="cipher" class="bootstrap-switch"/>
```

CAction.php
There maybe something wrong here

```
case 'postConfession':
  $cipher = $_POST['ciphered'] === '1' ? '1' : '0';
  $conn = new Manner;
  $conn->postconfession($_POST['confession'], $_POST['id'], $cipher);
  break;
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    //comment button click

   $("#confessbtn").click(function () {
var text = $("#content");
var ew = $("#drFSDUGAHEVUIEU");
var mew = $("#NSSIOWYDBEI");

if ($.trim(text.val()) === "") {
  $("#error").html("<span class='help-inline is-invalid'>"+$languages.message+"</span>")
  return;
}

$.ajax({
  url: 'CEngine/CAction.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    action: 'postConfession',
    confession: text.val(),
    id: ew.val(),
    ciphered: mew.val()

  },
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#confessbtn").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> &nbsp; Confessing...')
  },
  success: function (result) {
    location.reload();
  }
});
});
```

Maybe here this is the code to send it to the database

```
 public function postconfession($confession, $id, $ciphered) {

try {
  $uid = $this->generateuid();
  //$confession = $_POST['confession'];
  //$id = $_POST['id'];
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $message = htmlentities($confession, ENT_QUOTES);
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO confessions (uid, message, user_id, ciphered, ip) VALUES (:u, :m, :id, :c, :i)");
  $stmt->bindParam(":u", $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(":m", $message, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(":c", $ciphered, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(":i", $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {

  echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
}


 }
```

Comment: In your `postconfession` from where you get this `$mc`? It's not defined and may fallback to database default column value

Comment: Sorry, it was $ciphered

Comment: in your CAction.php you check for `$_POST["ciphered"]` but your checkbox name is `cipher`

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo

Comment: @ItsFlo Ajax is sending `ciphered`

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_POST)` to show us values?

Comment: Please note that if you do not check checkbox, then no value is sent (`$_POST` does not have key `ciphered`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkboxes (and radiobuttons) work a bit differently than other inputs.
Their value never actually changes but they have an additional `checked` attribute. So if you want your CheckBox to be checked by default you have to set the HTML attribute `checked`.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="NSSIOWYDBEI" value="1" checked="checked"  name="cipher" class="bootstrap-switch"/>
```

JQuerys `.val()` function returns the value of the input as expected but since that never changes for checkboxes, you will always get your preset value.

In Javascript you could check for the `checked` attribute of an Element which returns a boolean.
To get that value in jquery you can use `.prop("checked")`.

```js
$.ajax({
    data: {
        ciphered: mew.prop("checked")
  },
};
```

Since this returns a boolean, you have to adjust your PHP check aswell.

```php
$cipher = $_POST['ciphered'] === 'true' ? '1' : '0';
```